# Cannot grab Image file using fetch in PHP

Tags: php, fetch, multipartform-data

We have a widget built using React that uses the following code to send form data from user input to another server :

```
let resp  = await fetch(url , {
            method: 'post',
            body: formData
        })
```

The `formdata` is sent to a PHP file that grabs the information and stores it in a data table and sends an email containing the information to our support team. I used the code below to verify that I was getting the information on the server:

```
$input = file_get_contents('php://input');
  error_log($input);
```

and I could see this in the error log:

```
    ------WebKitFormBoundaryiUhA3VJVz1oW5MyG
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Location"

testing
------WebKitFormBoundaryiUhA3VJVz1oW5MyG
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Comments"

gxmzxfhmfzm
------WebKitFormBoundaryiUhA3VJVz1oW5MyG
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Assist"

I think I found an error
------WebKitFormBoundaryiUhA3VJVz1oW5MyG
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Image"

[object File]...(etc)
```

I was able to figure out how to get all string objects, but I cannot seem to grab the `[object File]` which is supposed to be an image. My `$_FILES` is an empty array.

My php.ini settings are as follows:

```
file_uploads = On
post_max_size = 2M
upload_max_filesize = 2M
```

The image is only 33kb.

How do I access this image file to store/send in an email?

EDIT:
Here is the form code as requested.

```
<form className="flex-column form" encType="multipart/form-data">
            <Input
                label="Location"
                name="Location"
                type="text"
                register={register}
                error={errors["Location"]}
                placeholder="Home, Library, Starbucks, office, etc."
            />
            <Textarea
                label="Comments"
                name="Comments"
                error={errors["Comments"]}
                placeholder="Please be specific. Include the error code message if applicable. The more details, the better."
                register={register({required: `Comments are required`})}
            />
            <Select
                name="Assist"
                label="How can we assist you?"
                options={selectOptions}
                register={register}
                error={errors["Assist"]}
            />
            <ImageInput
                label="Load the file"
                name="Image"
                register={register}
                images={watch('Image')}
                accept="image/png, image/jpg, image/jpeg, image/gif"
                onChange={handleFileLoad}
                error={errors["Image"]}
            />
            <Button
                onClick={handleSubmit(submitForm)}
                classes="button button-black"
                label="Submit"
            />
        </form>
```

Comment: This content-type should populate the $_FILES array correctly. Are you sure the code does not output any errors?

Comment: @vuryss I do not see any errors in the error log, and the code runs fine. When the $_FILES array is checked, no files are found and it simply continues without the file.

Comment: Can you post the form here? There might be something missing there. It usually adds a content-type header in the part that contains the file... that seems to be missing here.

Comment: Ah shoot, remove that headers fields, you should not use that. It should put the boundary there automatically. This overwrites it and the PHP cannot see which is the separator that separates the different form data.

Comment: @vuryssOkay I will give that a shot and let you know. That would make sense as the $_POST was also empty and I had to grab that information a different way.

Comment: @vuryss So this fixed one issue in that I was actually able to populate the $_POST array, but the $_FILES array is still blank.

Comment: Ok then show me how you fill in the formData object :)

Comment: @vuryss I have fixed it. It looks like the file was being appended as part of the POST information which isn't supposed to happen. Thank you for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It seems that when the form was submitted, the file was being placed as part of the $_POST array and was being converted to just a string. When done correctly, none of the file information should be shown in the $_POST array, only the $_FILE array.